# Как избавиться от мусорных символов OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, github, openssl

Говоря вкратце я пишу либу для работы с гитхаб апи и либу для работы с сетью. Для https запросов используются сокеты и openssl. суть проблемы такова: в теле ответа постоянно появляются какие то левые символы. по http всё работает нормально и я не думаю что это гитхаб косячит но проблему я найти не могу.. сами символы появляются уже на выходе из SSL_read()... прикрепил скрины с отпутом и показал стрелками мусорные символы... что делаю не так? откуда они берутся?

вот [тут](https://github.com/Dzhekson6000/SiTNetwork/blob/master/source/Network/Socket.cpp) почти весь код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где кусок кода, который это печатал ? Может вы просто 0 в конец данных перед печатью не записали ...

Comment: @Mike нет. Я на 50ую строчку [этого](https://github.com/Dzhekson6000/SiTNetwork/blob/master/source/Http/HttpSocketClient.cpp) файла  добавил `perror(request.str().c_str());`

Comment: Вы конечно хорошо придумали `result = Socket::read(buffer, 1024, 0);
        buffer[1024]='\0';` А что если данных меньше, чем 1024, 0 надо все таки записать в конец данных, т.е. посмотреть сколько реально считано и туда записать...

Comment: @Mike я тоже это заметил и уже пофиксил но не запушил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти символы это [чанки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). В моём случае **ab** или **6c** это размеры чанков в виде хекс, а конец передачи это кусок нулевого размера(то бишь 0). Вот так вот. Реализован в 1.1 поэтому, чтобы это проверить нужно просто изменить версию на HTTP 1.0.